# How to deal with a large number of outliers in biological data?

Tags: r, outliers, biostatistics

I´m working on a marine species dataset with R. I would like to compare the biomass and abundance between different sites but I´m not sure how to deal with the large number of outliers. I am aware that my outliers are not "real outliers": it´s more that my data are not well described by a normal distribution. Therefore I think it would be wrong to ignore/withdraw them because of their biological meaning. Would it be wise to transform my data? Or to leave it like it is and use robust statistical techniques to run my analysis?

Here is a brief overview of my data:

```
bio_reorder <- my_data %>% ggplot( aes(x=site, y= biomass,fill = site)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to compare the biomass and abundance between different sites but I´m not sure how to deal with the large number of outliers

From top of my head, it seems to me you want to fit a linear model as `biomass ~ site` to make inference about the estimate of "site". Given the characteristics of the response variable, the easiest approach to try is to log-transform biomass and use a standard linear model (`lm` in R) or apply a generalised linear model (`glm`) with appriopriate family distirbution and link function, perhaps using a Gamma family.

Comment: (+1) Details can be very sensitive to whether there are recorded zeros, For example, a log transformation needs modification in that case, but a generalized linear model with logarithmic link can work well with a modest fraction of zeros as the point is that the mean function is positive. (In general, I see nothing pathological in your display, but essentially what I would expect with ecological data.)  Poisson might be appropriate as a first try, especially if, but not only if, abundance is counted.

Comment: For visualization (although probably not for analysis) I recommend log(measure + 1) scale if zeros are present.